# iOS app rejected for using WhatsApp

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I submitted an iOS app for a family member that does the following: displays products, stored in Firebase, that this family member sells in a tableview. When clicking on a cell, a view with more details about this product is displayed. Then, the user can add it to his/her shopping cart. In the main view, there's a shopping cart button that opens another view showing the items the user has chosen to purchase. Then, in the same view there's a button that says "submit" that will send the user's items to a specific number via WhatsApp. If WhatsApp is not installed, then an alert message will be shown asking the user to install it to submit the order. Otherwise, the message will be sent via WhatsApp. The app works just fine.

I submitted this app to Apple's app store but my app was rejected. Apple said that the reason is my app needs to have WhatsApp installed on the user's iOS device so that my app works.

Any suggestions to resolve this issue? Any other way to send/submit users' orders?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for third-party support regarding the Apple App store

Answer (score 1):

The App Store model relies on users' assumption that an app can stand by itself, and does not require other applications installed in order to invoke core functionality. You solution is already retrieving data from Firebase, the path of least resistance from now sounds like it'd be devising functionality to send the data back there to replace the functionality that's currently farmed out to WhatsApp.

Is your processing flow currently utilizing the data from WhatsApp to charge the customer? How are you collecting payment information? What does your authentication mechanism look like? You could leverage whatever payment platform is currently handling these tenets of your application to retrieve individual purchase data.

---

You mention this app is for "a family member" - this use case is extremely narrow and not supported in the wider App Store distribution model. If building a back-end database (or similar) is not a viable option, consider doing an ad-hoc deployment to a particular device where you are 100% sure that WhatsApp is previously installed.